# Open link in a new window in current space

Tags: spaces, web-browser, links

Say I have two spaces:

1. Slack, VS Code, or some app
2. Safari/Edge/Chrome/etc.

If I click on a link in an app in `1` I want it to open a new browser window in `1`. Right now it switches to `2` and opens the window in an existing/open browser in `2`.

Is this possible?

I saw some other similar questions but they are asking about using Apple Script and that is not what I want. Unless I have to somehow have some kind of intercepter for links.

Answer (score 1):

I have the option "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application" unchecked and yet if I have a firefox window open in another desktop, if I right click on firefox in the docket and click "open new window", it switches me to the desktop where the other firefox window is and then opens a new window there.

I found a way to stop this from happening. If you right click on the firefox icon in the dock, then options, select "none" under the "assign to" section. Now when I have a blank desktop, I can open a new firefox window in that desktop when there is already another firefox window open in another desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS User Guide there is article [Work in multiple spaces on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/mac) which says:

> By default, when switching to an app, the desktop automatically switches to a space that has open windows for the app. For example, if you create a new TextEdit document in Desktop 3, but TextEdit windows are already open in Desktop 2, your new document opens in Desktop 2. To change this setting, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Mission Control , then deselect the checkbox for switching.

This checkbox is called "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application"

Comment: I have that setting unchecked. It still does not work as expected.